# Is it possible to install Integration Runtime on virtual AWS server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-data-factory

I need to connect Azure data factory to an AWS virtual server which is on a private network. It is using Windows 2008R2 with SQl Server 2008 R2.
Therefore, it looks like I need to install Microsoft’s Integration Runtime service behind the firewall to allow self-hosted integrated runtime to run on the data factory.
I can't find anything online about whether this can be installed onto an AWS virtual server. Can this be done? and can anyone point me towards documentation / tutorials about how to do this?

Comment: Please edit to show your work and specific issue(s). As written, this is a doc/tutorial request.

Answer (score 0):

According with [Create and configure a self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory) it is possible to install **Integration Runtime** on a virtual AWS server. Azure Data Factory supports deploying the Integration Runtime on a virtual machine in a customer-managed environment. You can create an EC2 Instance (following [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#prerequisites) in AWS and then install the Integration Runtime on that machine.

Before you proceed with the installation, you should make sure that the virtual machine meets the Integration Runtime's system requirements. You will also need to configure the necessary ports on the NSG (following [Ports and firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#ports-and-firewalls)) to ensure that it can communicate with the Azure Data Factory and any other data sources that you want to connect to.

Once you have configured the virtual machine, you can download and install the Integration Runtime software onto the virtual machine, and then register it with your Azure Data Factory.

Hoping it helps